# Vim: Custom Folding for special doc

Tags: vim

Here is the code:

```
package localhost

import scala.tools.nsc.reporters._
import scala.tools.nsc.util.Position


class MyReporter extends Reporter {


  /** <p>
   *    Give message of an rejected program
   *  </p>
   */
  def info0(pos: Position, msg: String, severity: Severity, force: Boolean) = {
    severity match {
      case INFO =>
      case WARNING =>
      case ERROR => println("error on pos: " +pos+" message: "+msg)
    }
  }
}
```

So I want to to fold

```
  /** <p>
   *    Give message of an rejected program
   *  </p>
   */
```

to something like:

```
/** */
```

How is this possible?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be this:

```
:set foldmarker=/*,*/
:set foldmethod=marker
```

Those folded lines then appear like this:

```
+--  4 lines: * <p>------------------------------
```

With a little more work, you might be able to create a `'foldtext'` expression that would create the desired folded line from elements of the first and last line of the folded region. However, `:help foldtext()` says that "Leading white space, "//" or "/*" and the text from the 'foldmarker' and 'commentstring' options is removed," so you may not be able to get exactly the appearance that you want.

Comment: Garyjohn: Slick.  As a newby, I note that :foldo! opens all folds and :foldc! closes all folds

Comment: @Rolnik: You can also use `zR` and `zM`, which in common cases have the same effect and are a little faster to type.